# Visual desginer in form inherited "<T>"

Tags: c#, forms, designer, inherited

this dont work in designer view ....

```
public partial class FMain : IMasterForm<Familia>
{
    public FMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

but this... is Ok in desginer view! ...

```
public partial class FMain : Fbase 
{
    public FMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class Fbase : IMasterForm<Familia>
{
    public Fbase() { }
}
```

i found this answer here: 
http://madprops.org/blog/Designing-Generic-Forms/

But i Would need to operate it without creating another extra class. Its Possible?

Comment: Is `IMasterForm<T>` an interface or a class? The name suggests an interface, but I have a feeling it isn't...

Comment: Is a class, i need class.... :S

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted the base class, which is Form. Probably you have replaced it with the interface.

The correct class declaration would be:

```
public partial class Fbase: Form, IMasterForm<Familia>
```

Comment: fixed. actually - Fbase should be inherited from form

Comment: Cant inherited Form because IMasterForm inherited Form yet